# Passing multiple dataframes from a list into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a problem facing with lists, list where each value has two columns like a whole data frame. how do I pass each value into a new data frame?
For suppose, I have three dataframes which are loaded into list name A as shown below

```
df10 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}) 
df20 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}) 
df30 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}) 
A = [df10,df20,df30]
```

the output for this will be:

```
[ one two 0 1.0 4.0 1 2.0 3.0 2 3.0 2.0 3 4.0 1.0, one two 0 1.0 4.0 1 2.0 3.0 2 3.0 2.0 3 4.0 1.0, one two 0 1.0 4.0 1 2.0 3.0 2 3.0 2.0 3 4.0 1.0]
```

Now I want to get back those data frames out of the list, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you post your example as runnable python code? Your example isn't very clear. You have multiple dataframes in a list and you want to assign each of these to variables called `df1`, `df2` and etc...? That seems unrelated to putting them in a new dataframe.

Comment: If you had a list of dataframes with the same column names, `pd.concat(my_list)` should do the trick.

Comment: The list is not a valid python list

Comment: For suppose, I have three dataframes which are loaded into list name A as shown below df10 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
df20 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
df30 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
A = [df10,df20,df30]

Comment: Now A will return me the below output : [   one  two
 0  1.0  4.0
 1  2.0  3.0
 2  3.0  2.0
 3  4.0  1.0,
    one  two
 0  1.0  4.0
 1  2.0  3.0
 2  3.0  2.0
 3  4.0  1.0,
    one  two
 0  1.0  4.0
 1  2.0  3.0
 2  3.0  2.0
 3  4.0  1.0]                                                                                                                  Now I want to get back those data frames out of the list, how do I do that?

Comment: please update the question using edit option instead of adding example in the comments.

Comment: @Ramdr I don't understand the requirement, if you want the individual dataframe, you already have `df10`,`df20`,`df30`

Comment: @SuhasMucherla basically there are multiple sheets in an excel file where i pushed them into a list where  each sheet is defined a df. Now I ran this into a function which gives multiple data frames and now this are stored in a form of list. Now i want them out of the lists. To make it simple I have given the above example.

Comment: `A[0]` is `df10`, `A[1]` is `df20` and `A[2]` is `df30`

Comment: @Ramdr I Think you have to index each dataframe out of the list manually

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Lambda in the comments, access individual item of the list by using index. See [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for more.

```
import pandas as pd

# define 3 different dataframes
df10 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}) 
df20 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [3., 4., 5., 6.], 'two' : [6., 5., 4., 3.]}) 
df30 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [7., 8., 9., 0.], 'two' : [0., 9., 8., 7.]}) 

# combine them in the list
A = [df10,df20,df30] 

# access each item of the list (dataframe) directly by using index (A[i])
print(A[0],"\n")
print(A[1],"\n")
print(A[2],"\n")

# access all items (dataframes) in the loop
for x in A:
    print(x,"\n")
```